# What's the easiest way to break bedrock in 1.16.5?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What's the easiest method to break the bedrock in 1.16.5?
And which are the materials needed?

Also, can I easily tunnel down through multiple in survival mode?

Comment: Heavily depends on how much bedrock you need to break. Methods that are quick&easy for a single block become unmanageable chore for 50 and impossible for 1000. On the other hand, machines capable of removing a million bedrock blocks are a total overkill if you need to remove a dozen.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in 1.16.5 there was a glitch involving pistons.

Here's a video tutorial of that method, which is a bit complicate to explain by text:

Materials needed:

- 1x block
- 1x lever
- 2x regular pistons
- 1x trap door
- 1x obsidian
- 2x TNT

> This method is 100% reliable requiring no luck, and you can punch a hole in nether ceiling in under 30 seconds. With this technique you can break any unbreakable block, not just bedrock.